# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous when trying to plot DataFrame with Datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python

I want to plot stacked bars using plotly express. I load the data from a .csv file but for simplification I have tried to rplicate some smaple data in my code snippet below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {'Date': ['2020-09-17', '2020-09-18', '2020-09-20', '2020-09-21', '2020-10-17', '2020-10-18', '2020-10-20', '2020-10-21'],
    'Amount (EUR)': [-25.93, -18.57, -53.07, -166.50, -2.93, -15.57, -11.07, -80.50],
    'Category': ['Food', 'Car', 'Food', 'House', 'Car', 'Food', 'Food', 'Car']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df = df.groupby([df.index.to_period('M'), 'Category']).agg({'Amount (EUR)':"sum"}).unstack()

fig = px.bar(df,
         x=df.index,
         y='Amount (EUR)',
         barmode='stack',
         template='plotly_dark',
         color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.T10,
         title='Amount by category per month')

fig.show()
```

I recieve the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous.
```

Even after searching this site and others for several hours now, I do not understand this error message in this context. What do I have to do to get the figure?

**EDIT** full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_5280/3267266995.py in ?()
      1 # darstellung Kategorie-Stapelsäulen pro Monat
----> 2 fig = px.bar(df,
      3              x=df.index,
      4              y='Amount (EUR)',
      5              barmode='stack',

~/Dokumente/jupyter/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/express/_chart_types.py in ?(data_frame, x, y, color, pattern_shape, facet_row, facet_col, facet_col_wrap, facet_row_spacing, facet_col_spacing, hover_name, hover_data, custom_data, text, base, error_x, error_x_minus, error_y, error_y_minus, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, color_continuous_scale, pattern_shape_sequence, pattern_shape_map, range_color, color_continuous_midpoint, opacity, orientation, barmode, log_x, log_y, range_x, range_y, text_auto, title, template, width, height)
    369     """
    370     In a bar plot, each row of `data_frame` is represented as a rectangular
    371     mark.
    372     """
--> 373     return make_figure(
    374         args=locals(),
    375         constructor=go.Bar,
    376         trace_patch=dict(textposition="auto"),

~/Dokumente/jupyter/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in ?(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
   2072     trace_patch = trace_patch or {}
   2073     layout_patch = layout_patch or {}
   2074     apply_default_cascade(args)
   2075 
-> 2076     args = build_dataframe(args, constructor)
...
   1520             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1521             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1522         )

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**EDIT 2** This is what I am looking for (done with `df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`) but done with plotly:
[image: Stacked bar plot]

Comment: Please post the [full error message with traceback](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Comment: And please make a [mre]. I'd start by translating the labels. For specifics see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Full traceback is added to the post. The labels are irrelevant since they are only used to categorize the data and define the stacks per bar in the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/cc887531-7391-4e94-81ac-a2de5e94d9cb/view-source)

---

***Update*** :

You can try :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.index = df.pop("Date")

df = (
    df.groupby([df.index.to_period('M'), 'Category'])
        .agg({'Amount (EUR)':"sum"}).reset_index()
        .assign(Date= lambda x: x["Date"].astype(str))
)

fig = px.bar(df,
             x="Date", y="Amount (EUR)",
             color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.T10,
            template='plotly_dark', color="Category",
             title="Amount by category per month",
             width=600, height=500
            )

fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='category')

fig.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: I had an Multiindex before because I first grouped by `df.index.year` and `df.index.mont`. Thats why I switched to `df.index.to_period('M')` to only have one index column. While what you have done seems to work in some way, now it seems that the categories are no more visible in the chart...

Comment: I'm talking about the columns (*see the tight dict above*) that are a MultiIndex in your case. And regarding your last point, I have no idea because your should make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) first.

Comment: Alongside some sample code I also added a picture of what I try to achieve as a chart. Hope this makes it more clear. Also I just now understood what you meant. I did not now that my index column is in fact two...

Comment: Thank you. I made an update to address your issue. Can you check it out ?

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to work! However my dates on x axis are unsorted even if i sort the date column of the dataframe. Do you have one last hint for me here?

Comment: That's weird, because with `xaxis_type='category'`, plotly is supposed to maintain the original order (*like in the plot above*). You're welcome ;)

Comment: By using `barmode='relative'` instead of `barmode='stack'` I have achieved correct rendering of negative and positive values around the x axis. The sorting can be achieved by `fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='category ascending')`.

Comment: Good to know and well done. Happy coding ;)